# Server always returning 403 forbidden even when user has the role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication

I just finished my logging/logout code on my asp.net web core application and I am having a problem where the server always returns error 403 forbidden when trying to access a method that needs a specific role. What can be the problem? I checked the database and the role assignment is working fine.
here is an example of a method I wrote for the test:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
[HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public string Test()
{
return "role checking working";
}
```

My actual user does have the role "SuperAdmin" but I still get the forbidden from the server, by the way, I made sure to send the token with the request. When I tried just `[Authorize]`, the check works fine since I only access that method when logged in.

Could it be the code generating the token? since I had no idea how to do that part and I just followed a tutorial brainlessly

Edit:
here is my `claims` variable when creating the token

```
var claims = new[]{
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
};
```

what should I add to it?

Comment: Your token must have a `ClaimsIdentity` with the user roles as `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)`.

Comment: @HMZ thanks for your reply, I tried adding your code but it not compiling, I edited the post to show my actual claims, how can I add the roles?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I found the solution after searching following what you pointed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I thought that the token I was creating contains the user information and his roles but I actually needed to add them manually, here is the right `claims` code that adds the roles to the token.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),

new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    };

var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
}
```